# how to auto complete string literal in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, ide, visual-assist

It seems that VS( with VisualAssist installed) do not support string literal auto completion, am I missing something? Or is there an extension to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that Visual Studio doesn't support auto completion for string literals.

> The IntelliSense options may not work as you expect in certain cases.
>   ...
>   **The cursor is in a string literal.**   You can't use IntelliSense if the
>   cursor is in the quotation marks around a string literal.
>   *Source:
>   [Troubleshooting IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx#Anchor_5)*

Although I have to add to this that in some languages IntelliSense does still give limited suggestions within the quotes.
For example in XAML when a reference is added (opening with a `{`).
Like in: `<TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"`